# QOpenGLWidget's context is null

Tags: qt, opengl, qml

I am trying to add a `QOpenGLWidget` to my `QGraphicsScene`, but the application crashes when I call `initializeOpenGLFunctions()`. I am pretty sure that the context of `OpenGLView` is null and that is why it is crashing (provides no logs) for two reasons:

1. When I print it, it outputs `0x0`
2. When I try to enable `QOpenGLDebugLogger` it outputs that there is no current context.

I thought that QOpenGLWidget would have an OpenGLContext out of the box. Any idea why the context is not getting set? Am I missing something in my initialization?

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setVersion(3, 2);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);


OpenGLView view = new OpenGLView();
```

header

```
class OpenGLView : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
}
```

```
#include "OpenGLView.h"

OpenGLView::OpenGLView(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent) {
    initializeGL();
}


void OpenGLView::initializeGL() {
    initializeOpenGLFunctions(); // crashes
//    ...
}

void OpenGLView::paintGL() {
//    ...
}

void OpenGLView::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
//    ...
}
```

Comment: Could be many things, like not having support for GL 3.2

Comment: I do have support for GL 3.2. Been using OpenGL apart from QT with that version.

Comment: `OpenGLView` doesn't inherits `QOpenGLFunctions`. Where is that `initializeOpenGLFunctions()` function?

Comment: It does, I updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you called `initializeGL()` in the constructor. By that time, the context has not been initialized. The context is first initialized when the widget is shown. Details taken from [Qt's source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qopenglwidget.cpp.html#_ZN20QOpenGLWidgetPrivate10initializeEv) below:

```
void QOpenGLWidgetPrivate::initialize()
{
    Q_Q(QOpenGLWidget);
    if (initialized)
        return;
    
    ...

    QScopedPointer<QOpenGLContext> ctx(new QOpenGLContext);
    ctx->setFormat(requestedFormat);
    if (shareContext) {
        ctx->setShareContext(shareContext);
        ctx->setScreen(shareContext->screen());
    }
    if (Q_UNLIKELY(!ctx->create())) {
        qWarning("QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context");
        return;
    }

    ...

    context = ctx.take();
    initialized = true;
    q->initializeGL();
}

bool QOpenGLWidget::event(QEvent *e)
{
    Q_D(QOpenGLWidget);
    switch (e->type()) {

    ...

    case QEvent::Show: // reparenting may not lead to a resize so reinitalize on Show too
        if (d->initialized && window()->windowHandle()
                && d->context->shareContext() != QWidgetPrivate::get(window())->shareContext())
        {
            // Special case: did grabFramebuffer() for a hidden widget that then became visible.
            // Recreate all resources since the context now needs to share with the TLW's.
            if (!QCoreApplication::testAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts))
                d->reset();
        }
        if (!d->initialized && !size().isEmpty() && window()->windowHandle()) {
            d->initialize();
            if (d->initialized)
                d->recreateFbo();
        }
        break;

    ...

    }
    return QWidget::event(e);
}
```

Comment: This helps, I am now getting a non-null context, but still crashes when calling initializeOpenGLFunctions

Comment: What does the debugger say this time?

Comment: same thing "The program has unexpectedly finished."

Comment: Resolved it - there was a nullptr that took sometime to find.